# How to add shopping cart rule based on amount of calculated shipping?

Tags: shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules

what I would like to be able to do is apply a shopping cart discount based on the calculated shipping from UPS or Fedex.  The idea is, I build $20 into the price of our products.  Any order that has shipping $20 or under gets Free Shipping.  Any order that has shipping over $20 pays the full shipping amount, however gets a $20 discount so they aren't overpaying for shipping.  Is this at all possible with current cart rules or will it require some new programming?

Thanks,

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: not as of yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This requires custom programming, possibly via an already-available third-party module.

Comment: Keyul: this answer is within the scope of the original question.